# Rank not being determined properly

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm using this query:

```
SELECT A.place_idx,A.place_id,B.TOTAL_CNT,(@r := @r + 1) AS rank FROM CUSTOM_LIST
AS A
INNER JOIN
(SELECT  @r := 0)
AS C
INNER JOIN
(SELECT place_id,COUNT(place_id) AS TOTAL_CNT from COUNT_TABLE GROUP BY place_id)
AS B ON B.place_id=A.place_id order by B.TOTAL_CNT desc;
```

Which gives this result:

[image: 1]

But I want this result:

[image: 2]

How do I need to modify my query? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT *,(@r := @r + 1) AS rank FROM 
(
  SELECT A.place_idx,A.place_id,B.TOTAL_CNT FROM CUSTOM_LIST
  AS A
  INNER JOIN
  (SELECT place_id,COUNT(place_id) AS TOTAL_CNT from COUNT_TABLE GROUP BY place_id)
  AS B ON B.place_id=A.place_id order by B.TOTAL_CNT desc
) AS T, (SELECT  @r := 0) AS tt
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'T, (SELECT  @r := 0) AS tt' at line 9

Comment: i find! 3 line (SELECT A.place_idx  i removed ( < this

Answer (score 0):

Your C.rank is getting calculated as they are processed, not after they are sorted.  There is really no need for this data, anyways.  Since you're sorting the rows by your metric, you know the first row is the first rank, etc.  You can handle it on the programming side of things after you pull it out.

Alternatively, you can put what you have in an inner select, then do the rank after.

Comment: Someone posted the latter solution.